# Elegant way to handle two options, when both is also an option

Tags: python, enum, dictionary

In the simplest case, I have some code where the user may want to do one thing (a), another thing, (b), or both (a+b).

The options are reasonably complex and have their own functions, but I would like an elegant way of executing one, the other, or multiple.

I want to consider the types of the choices supplied, as I think this could add unnecessary complexity when expanding to more options.

Dictionaries:

```py
def execute(choices: List[str]):
    options = {'a', a, 'b': b}

    for choice in choices:
        options[choice]()

# could also be empty, or contain only 'a' or 'b':
choices = ['a', 'b']
execute(choices)
```

Enums:

```py
class Choice(Enum):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()
    BOTH = auto()

def execute(choice: Choice):
    if choice.name == 'A':
        a()
    elif choice.name == 'B':
        b()
    elif choice.name == 'BOTH':
        a()
        b()
```

Keyword argument options:

```py
def execute(*, a=False, b=False):
    if a:
        a()
    if b:
        b()
```

Combining dicts and enums:

```py
class Choice(Enum):
    A = auto()
    B = auto()

def execute(choices: List[Choice]):
    options = {
        'A': a,
        'B': b,
    }

    for choice in choices:
        options[choice.name]()
```

I think the last option will scale the best. Short of supplying a config file, am I missing something? I can use Python 3.10 so perhaps match case could be of use.

Are there considerations to be made for extended cases e.g. "cannot perform option C when performing option A", perhaps an option validation function as well?

Please consider typing and scalability.

Comment: Why not make the options a bitmask, so they can be combined arbitrarily. For example: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a7715ccfba5b86ab09f86ec56ac3755c93b46b48/Lib/re/_constants.py#L206-L215

Comment: Looks like a strategy pattern would be the way to go to handle this

Comment: Strategy pattern would put you on the path to [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a `Flag` is what you want:

```
from enum import Flag

class Choice(Flag):
    #
    A = auto()
    B = auto()
    C = auto()
    #
    def is_valid(self):
        if Choice.A in self and Choice.C in self:
            return False
        return True

def execute(choices):
    #
    options = {
            Choice.A: do_a,
            Choice.B: do_b,
            }
    #
    if not choices.is_valid():
        raise Exception(f'Invalid choice: {choices}')
    #
    for choice in choices:
        options[choice]()
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: This doesn't work, what is the type of the argument choices here? You treat it as both an enum, and a list to be iterated over.

Comment: @QuantumChris: As the author of Python's enum, I assure you it does work.  (Just to make sure, I added the `do_x` functions and tested. ;) I hate when I make typos.)

Comment: Oh, to answer your question: the argument is a `Choice` such as `Choice.A` or `Choice.A|Choice.C`.  If you want to accept integers as well, add a `choices = Choice(choices)` in `execute()`.